# How to navigate Inner view controller from App delegate

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, swrevealviewcontroller

in my app delegate this is how I navigate to my `SWRevealViewController`

```
let revealViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RevealView") as? SWRevealViewController


        self.window!.rootViewController = revealViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I navigate to that inner view controller from the `SWRevealViewController`'s `FrontViewcontroller`like this.

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Read") as! ReadViewController
        secondViewController.title = self.selectedTitle
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Now in `AppDelegate` when receive a push notification I want to navigate this `ReadViewController`. and when I click the back button it should come back to the `FrontViewController` just like it happens in normal way. How can I do this in my notification delegates in `AppDelegate`
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let yourVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Read") as! ReadViewController

let frontViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("frontViewController") as! FrontViewController

let navController = UINavigationController()
navController.viewControllers  = [yourVC,frontViewController]

self.window!.rootViewController = navController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```